# Need help setting up (mining)

Tags: mining-setup

I have a new GPU is has 16 GB of RAM and I downloaded the wallet so I can set upon mining a block, but I do not know what I am doing. Can I get some help?

Answer (score 1):

First, using a GPU for Monero mining is not particularly wise. Monero's mining algorithm, RandomX, favors CPUs.

Second, you'll get much better hashrate using a dedicated miner (e.g. [XMRig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig)) than using the wallet.

Third, I suggest you review the [r/MoneroMining FAQ](https://np.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/comments/lt9xzj/faqs_for_noobs_read_this_before_posting/).